# What is the maximal l for a $C^{l}$-vector field on a $C^{k}$-manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

Given a $C^{k}$-manifold what is the maximal $l$ that allows to have a good definition of a $C^{l}$-vector field on that manifold? In some textbooks is given a definition with $l=k-1$ and restriction $k\ge2$, in others with $l=k$ without restriction on $k$, but there isn't a proof of one or other choice, only definition.

Is there a proof? Why the maximal $l$ is $l=k-1$ or $k=l$?

In these cases is the vector field still a derivation?

I've always had to deal with smooth manifold and so it's something new for me to consider this details.

Comment: Where did you see the $k=l$ claim? And what qualifies as a "good" definition in your mind?

Comment: means in a coordinate-independent way

Comment: Let me repeat: where did you see the claim $k=l$? On the face of it, the claim makes no sense.

Comment: As a general rule, do not trust any math claims made by physicists, unless you have a solid math reference for the claim.

Comment: Do you have any reference to study this case and why are you sure that $k=l$ is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151690/discussion-between-danilo-lombardo-and-moishe-kohan).

Comment: It is wrong because you loose one derivative when using a transition map between charts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation why $l=k-1$ is the right answer. Let $f: U\to U'$ be a $C^k$-smooth diffeomorphism of open subsets of ${\mathbb R}^n$, i.e. $f, f^{-1}$ are differentiable of order $k$  with continuous partial derivatives of order $k$. Note that by the inverse function theorem in ${\mathbb R}^n$ it suffices to assume that $f$ is a $C^k$-smooth bijection with invertible derivative at all points of $U$. Let $V$ be a $C^m$-smooth vector field on $U$. Then the "push-forward" of $V$ under $f$, denoted $f_*(V)$, is given by
$$
W(y)= Df(x)\cdot V(x), y=f(x). 
$$
For instance, even if $V$ is $C^\infty$, the matrix-valued function $Df(x)$ is only $C^{k-1}$-smooth and, hence, one expects $W(y)$ to be only $C^{k-1}$-smooth. Note that if $V$ is $C^m, m=k-1$ and $f$ is $C^k$, the vector field
$$
W(y)=Df(f^{-1}(y))\cdot V(f^{-1}(y))
$$
is at least $C^m$. (Composition and product of $C^m$-smooth maps is again $C^m$).

To check that one cannot do better than $m=k-1$, consider an example with $n=1$, $k=1$:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2+x& \text{if } x\ge 0\\
-x^2+x& \text{if } x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
This is a $C^1$-smooth diffeomorphism.

Take the constant vector field $V(x)=1$. (I intentionally do now use the math notation $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ for such vector fields since, most likely, you are not familiar with this formalism.) Then $W=f_*(V)$ is given by $f'(f^{-1}(y))$, i.e.
$$
W(y)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1+ 4y}& \text{if } y\ge 0\\
\sqrt{1- 4y}& \text{if } y\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
I will leave it to you to check that $W(y)$ is continuous but not differentiable, hence, you only get $m=k-1=0$-smoothness (i.e. continuity) of $W$ in this example, just as expected.

To conclude: If $M$ is a $C^k$-smooth manifold, you can define $C^{k-1}$-smooth vector fields on $M$ (as vector fields which are $C^{k-1}$-smooth in local coordinates) but not $C^k$-smooth vector fields on $M$.

Comment: As far as I understand you showed that a vector field on a $C^1$-manifold may be smooth w.r.t. one chart but only continuous w.r.t. another chart. But if a vector field happens to be smooth w.r.t. to each chart (even though the manifold is not smooth) it would still be legitimate to call the vector field smooth, wouldn't it? Or is this never the case?

Comment: @Filippo: It is almost never the case. Zero vector field I think is the only exception.